# $.each within $.each using JS multi-dimensional obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, each

I have an object created for some footer content like so:

```
var $footerObj = {
    "one" : {
        "title" : "One",
        "links" : {
            "A" : {
                "title" : "One A",
                "url" : "#",
                "external" : true
            },
            "B" : {
                "title" : "One B",
                "url" : "#",
                "external" : true
            },
            "C" : {
                "title" : "One C",
                "url" : "#",
                "external" : false
            }
        }
    },
    "two" : {
        "title" : "Two",
        "links" : {
            "A" : {
                "title" : "Two A",
                "url" : "#",
                "external" : false
            },
            "B" : {
                "title" : "Two B",
                "url" : "#",
                "external" : false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I am attempting to use jQuery's $.each to output this into some footer links.

```
$.each($footerObj, function(key, value) {

    $('.footer__links').append('<ul class="footer__list"></ul>');

    var $footerList = $('.footer__list');

    $.each(value.links, function(subkey, subvalue) {

        $footerList.append('<li class="footer__item"><a class="footer__link" href="' + subvalue.url + '">' + subvalue.title + '</a></li>');

    });

});
```

This is what I have but this causes the data in "two" to be outputted twice. I believe it's *value.links* in the 2nd $.each which is wrong but I've been going mad trying all different variations with no luck - any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append to a class it will append to every item that has that class, on the second object, there will be two with that calss, on the third there will be three, etc. The solution is to append to the one you created on that loop instead of every element with that class name. Do this in your outer `each()` loop instead:

```
var $footerList = $('<ul class="footer__list"></ul>');
$('.footer__links').append($footerList);
```

So it looks like this:

```
$.each($footerObj, function(key, value) {

    var $footerList = $('<ul class="footer__list"></ul>');

    $('.footer__links').append($footerList);

    $.each(value.links, function(subkey, subvalue) {

        $footerList.append('<li class="footer__item"><a class="footer__link" href="' + subvalue.url + '">' + subvalue.title + '</a></li>');

    });

});
```

Comment: Ah yes I was so sure that value.links was wrong I completely overlooked that. Thank you, worked!

Answer (score 0):

In your second `$.each` you are calling `$footerList` to append your element.

This variable is set in the first `$.each` and retrieve all the element with the class `footer__list`. On the second iteration of your first `$.each` you will have two

```
<ul class="footer__list"></ul>
```

Thus `$('.footer__list');` will return 2 elements and you will append your

```
'<li class="footer__item"><a class="footer__link" href="' + subvalue.url + '">' + subvalue.title + '</a></li>
```

to both of those elements, both of your `<ul>`